# how do I add a Text in flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I add my Text in the following code in flutter:

`Text( '${_productosModel[index].name}', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0), ),`

```
return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
//code TEXT
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: You mean, if the CachedNetworkImage failed to get the image from the URL, just show the images name?

Comment: what I need is that below the image show me the text field that I mention

Comment: Ohh in that case, you can use the Column widget, you can wrap CachedImageNetwork with Column, and then you can add Text below your images.

Comment: how would it look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIke this --- as the
heathscliff says,

```js
return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Column(children: [
Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
//code TEXT
          },
        ),
Text('data test'),
]),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `Expanded` with `Column`.
But I recommand you to use `Container` instead `Expanded`
Set the height and width of your `Container`

```
return InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity //if you want to use the maximum width
                    height: 250, // you can customize this
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl:
                          '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      placeholder: (_, __) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                            radius: 15,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Image text")
                ],
              ),
            );
```